# Why do transition elements specifically show complementary colours?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

When I searched for why the colour absorbed and emitted by coloured transitional elements are different , i found out that the metals absorb the light they need and the remaining is reflected .

But my doubt here is what happens to the absorbed light , i mean will it emit it? If yes, in what form ??

It can't absorb and reflect colours continuosly, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually a colored stuff absorbs a color, which helps its electrons to go to an excited state. Once excited, the atom or the molecule transfers this energy to the vibrations and rotations of the molecule : the agitation increases, and so the temperature. 
The energy may also be reemitted in light after the absorption process. This happens with fluorescent or phosphorescent substances, which are not numerous. In my opinion, no transition element have fluorescent or phosphorescent properties.